# extract sub expression with sed

Tags: linux, unix, shell, sed

I have a list of directories starting from /root. Eg

random text /root/dir1/files random end

delete me /root/dir1/files/2dir I am waste

/root/examples/source alalalala

/root/example/header some other text

I want to use sed to take from every line the directory and remove everything else. My final output must be

/root/dir1/files

/root/dir1/files/2dir

/root/examples/source

/root/example/header

How can I do it? (extract everything starting from /root... until the end of the path)

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

YET ANOTHER EDIT: Seems that my initial evaluation of the question did not really read it as closely as it should have. Thanks to the commentary below, I've learned a few tricks, and can clear up this answer.

First, [tylerl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/86060/tylerl) has shown a command that should work for this in sed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3495496/extract-sub-expression-with-sed/3495777#3495777). Neat trick, though I'll probably stick to awk for this.

My own solution did not take into account the first couple of lines given in the description. [ghostdog74](https://stackoverflow.com/users/131527/ghostdog74) gives a solution that might work [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3495496/extract-sub-expression-with-sed/3495713#3495713).

Take a look at the above linked solutions.

Comment: when you use awk/nawk, there is no need to use sed. `nawk '/^\/root/{print $1}'`. People often have the wrong impression that sed and awk work together, when in fact, awk is enough.

Comment: Sed will do it too. As will perl. As will bash. As will python... etc. Awk isn't "what you're looking for", but rather "another tool that will work".

Comment: @ghostdog74 That's much cleaner, very nice.

@tylerl I was not aware of that functionality with sed. Upvoted your answer below, as it directly answers the OP's question.

Comment: These print "random" and "delete" or nothing for the first two lines. It doesn't do what the OP wants. I don't know why it was accepted.

Comment: I am also not sure how this answer came to be accepted. I have updated with links to the two below solutions, both of which apply more rigidly to the question above. The answer has also been Community Wiki'd.

Answer (score 3):

Here you go:

```
sed 's|^[^/]*\(/[^ ]*\).*$|\1|'
```

This assumes that filenames don't have spaces in them, and the first "/" on the line marks the start of a filename.

Revise as:

```
sed -n 's|^[^/]*\(/[^ ]*\).*$|\1|p'
```

to only output lines that match the pattern (no blank lines).

Answer (score 2):

For the sake of gratuitous completeness, I've also included a solution in a few other languages:

Bash

```
while read LINE; do
  X=${LINE#*/}
  X=${X%% *}; 
  [ "$X" == "" ] || echo /$X
done
```

Perl

```
 perl -ne '/(\/root[^ ]+)/ and print "$1\n"'
```

Lua

```
#!lua
while true do
  local line = io.read()
  if line == nil then break end
  s = string.match(line,"/root[^%s]+")
  if s then print(s) end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i ~/\/root/) {print $i} }' file
```